# How to recover value of current line spread?

Tags: line-spacing, lengths

I want to set linespread to a value then go back to the previous value it had. How do I do it?

Something like:

```
\let\oldlinespread\linespreadvalue
\linespread{1}
\printmystuff
\linespread{\oldlinespread}
```

Comment: The parameter you want is `\baselinestretch`.

Comment: Use grouping and you won't need to reset the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is stored as `\baselinestretch`. However, your code would need something additional:

```latex
\let\savedbaselinestretch\baselinestretch

\linespread{1}\selectfont

<My stuff>

\linespread{\savedbaselinestretch}\selectfont
```

The blank lines are necessary.

A better way out is to use an environment:

```latex
\newenvironment{normalspread}
 {\par\linespread{1}\selectfont}
 {\par}

\begin{normalspread}
<My stuff>
\end{normalspread}
```

However, this would leave uneven spacing around the part with `\linespread{1}` (as would the naive code above.

A better example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{normalspread}
 {\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}\linespread{1}\selectfont}
 {\par}

\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-6]

\begin{normalspread}
\lipsum[2]
\end{normalspread}

\lipsum[3][1-6]

\end{document}
```

but the spacing has been added “by eye”.

[image]

Something better can be obtained with `setspace`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-6]

\begin{singlespace}
\lipsum[2]
\end{singlespace}

\lipsum[3][1-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't add dependencies to the document I'm working on. Also, the new spacing will be among two sections, so there won't be the problem of uneven spacing between two lines. So I believe the more rudimentary initial solutions will do for me. Thanks!